# How to save print paper size in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: printing, libreoffice, settings

I'm printing many Excel files everyday, each file has many sheets.

I'm going to print all sheets together in my own paper size like "longbond" but for every sheet I have to change one by one from "A4" to "longbond"!

How to set printer to my own paper size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the global default printer settings which LibreOffice respects in the system settings menu, section “Printers.”

Comment: what I mean is paper size, how to set default paper size to many sheets?what I see is always "A4" size..I'm sure this setting somewhere is saved..

Comment: The (default) paper size of the document is something very different from the paper size of the printer. Please edit your question to reflect that and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.